# Cforms II WordPress Mail Form error: Cannot redeclare class cf_mail

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having issues with a WordPress Cforms II booking form. The Cforms Mail form does not work:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class cf_mail in ../wp-content/plugins/cforms/lib_email.php on line 2

Does anyone have a good fix for this? Preferably without changing the core code?

On trying to backup the form settings for an upgrade as suggested here here: http://www.deliciousdays.com/cforms-plugin/ I went to `wp-admin/admin.php?page=cforms/cforms-global-settings.php` to backup form settings. I got onto an error page as well which said:

> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in the data transmission was detected.
>
> Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

As I cannot backup the form I cannot upgrade. I need to debug this. Bugs for the last two hours do not seem to show. The error log for yesterday is also empty. For now I prefer to fix the current plugin.

Comment: Well the data transmission error seems to be a Firefox 9 or FF profile issue. From Chrome I was able to back the global settings. Trying further steps now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I backed up he form settings I simply decided to do a clean installation of Cforms and then I imported the form settings. That worked well. Do not think I will use Cforms as much as a custom one or [Gravity forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) in the future..